# Making global user variable in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I have this code

```
Controller.php
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        view()->share('user', $this->user );
    }

HomeController.php
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

It didn't work so I debug it with debugger and I saw that  Auth::user() only return a user after finishing constructing.
i.e in HomeController@index() function
Any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That used to work in laravel 5.2, however in laravel 5.3 you can no longer access session variables or the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. So they provided a work around that looks like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors

Answer (score 1):

You can use `auth()->user()` or `Auth::user()` globally without creating any variables. You can use it even in views.

It's an auful idea to dublicate and store whole User object in a variable, session etc.

Comment: I use the user variable in my layout so I need it all the time. why is it so bad ?

Comment: You can use `auth()->user()` and `Auth::user()` in a view too. Dublicating whole object into a variable is against all good practices. Also, it will take a lot of additional memory (because user object is pretty big) for every request. You're also adding additional logic which you really do not need (since `Auth::` and `auth()` are really global) and you're making your code less readable for other developers when you reinvent the wheel and go against conventions.